# Odd redirection in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, memcached, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

I am getting odd redirection in general.  It works in development but not production.  Here are the responses for an update.  The same things happens on a create.

DEVELOPMENT

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/trackers
Completed 302 Found in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 18.7ms)
Started GET "/trackers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-06 06:41:02 -0600
```

PRODUCTION

```
Redirected to http://example.com/trackers
Completed 302 Found in 218ms (ActiveRecord: 63.9ms)
Started GET "/" for [IP} at 2014-01-05 20:15:33 +0000
```

routes.rb (pertinant)

```
              trackers GET    /trackers(.:format)                       trackers#index
                       POST   /trackers(.:format)                       trackers#create
           new_tracker GET    /trackers/new(.:format)                   trackers#new
          edit_tracker GET    /trackers/:id/edit(.:format)              trackers#edit
               tracker GET    /trackers/:id(.:format)                   trackers#show
                       PUT    /trackers/:id(.:format)                   trackers#update
                       DELETE /trackers/:id(.:format)                  trackers#destroy
```

Here is my tracker controller

```
class TrackersController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
load_and_authorize_resource

def create
  @tracker = params[:tracker]
  @user = current_user
  if @user.trackers.create(@tracker)
   redirect_to trackers_path, :notice => "New Tracker Created!"
  else
   redirect_to trackers_path, :notice => "Tracker Could not be created."
  end
end

def update
  @tracker = Tracker.find(params[:id])
  if @tracker.update_attributes(params[:tracker])
   redirect_to trackers_path, :notice => "Tracker Updated!"
  else
   redirect_to trackers_path(params[:id]), :notice => "Unable to Update Tracker"
  end
end

end
```

NGINX

```
upstream unicorn{
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.legalleads.sock fail_timeout=0;}


server {
listen      80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 https://$host;}


server {

listen 443 default;
server_name example.com;
root /home/a/apps/legalleads/public;
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;


location ^~ /assets/ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}

location @unicorn {
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: Also wanted to add that i'm getting other odd redirections, for instance when i update one controller it says to sent them back to the index page but it is going to the root_path.  Not sure what the best way to track this down is.

Comment: Please include routes.rb and the output from `rake routes`. Also, are you sure `current_user` is set correctly in `#silver`? I see `@current_user` and `current_user`.

Comment: Added information and also ran a rake precompile to make sure it wasn't asset related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faraz, thank you so much for the hint on this.  Here is the solution and the blog that helped me find the answer

http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2013/09/02/rails-ssl-route-generation-with-nginx-and-unicorn/

I had to tell nginx to keep the https.  This is why some of the time it would work and sometimes it would not.

```
location @unicorn {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}
```

Had to be changed to

```
location @unicorn {
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https; # New header for SSL
  proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect      off;
  proxy_pass          http://unicorn_something_server;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're chaining together renders and redirects in a way thats incompatible with the HTTP spec. From the limited part of your controllers that you've presented, I assume a `POST` request is being made on sign in, that feeds into a redirect, which then feeds into *yet another redirect or render*. That final redirect/render call is the culprit.

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

From [HTTP/1.1 Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

You should trace the logic in all of your callbacks to ensure that you call render/redirect only once at the end of a POST request.

Comment: I will trace through this but I think that this is going to be the reason.  I am certainly chaining multiple redirects and renders.  Will update once i work on this for a bit.

Comment: Also, remember that chaining responses makes for a poor user experience! Multiple redirects slows down your app significantly.

Comment: Since this is something that is only happening in production.  I added application.rb and the full controller.

Comment: Also in development has a GET "/trackers" where in production it is GET "/"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're running the app with SSL in production, no? As a test, run the app locally in production mode with SSL disabled and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks faraz, the SSL is handled by nginx where it listens to 80 and then redirects to 301 https://$host if it hears it. Rails server is unicorn proxy for nginx.  After removing SSL in production it works correctly.  I'll post my nginx.conf.  Oddly it had worked for several months without the odd redirection.